# Total canvas memory exceeds the maximum limit (224mb)

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, canvas, memory

I'm using this canvas gauges to visualize temperature and rpm of a sensor.
https://canvas-gauges.com/

When the canvas gauges reaches 224mb the gauges vanishes and the app stops working a bit later.

Is it possible to extend the memory or clear the cash? Would be sad to to step back to progressbars because the gauges looking realy professional...

Console log of the Error
[image]

This error occurs first in the linear and then in the radial gauge.
I tryed to .clear() every 5. value but it seems not to be a function anymore...

I'm running tests on an iPhone latest version (12.0) with the Cordova framework.
Thank you very much in advance.

Code examples:
First of all, the sensor provides me the values by BLE. I subscribed the characteristic which gives me the data in base64 which I convert in hex. I need to split the array and change the endianness. After that I pass the data to the right function e.g where the temperature gauge is drawn:

```
        var hex = base64toHEX(result.value);
        console.log("calc in Hex: "+hex);

        function split(hex){
            var commaSeperated = "";
            for(var i=0; i<=hex.length; i++){

                commaSeperated += hex.charAt(i);

                if(i==13 || i==17 || i==25 || i==27 || i==29){
                    commaSeperated += ",";
                }
            }
            return commaSeperated.split(',');
        }
        var nutzwerte = [];
        nutzwerte = split(hex);


        //COnvert Temp value in dezimal and pass to gauge_funktion
        var temp = parseInt(nutzwerte[3],16);
        new_temp_gauge(temp, Temp_max_global, G_temp_yellow,G_temp_red);
        switch_icon_temp(temp, Temp_max_global, G_temp_yellow,G_temp_red);
        document.getElementById("temp_aktuell").textContent = temp+"°C";
        console.log("Temperatur: "+temp+"°C");
```

This function draws the temperature gauge:

```
function new_temp_gauge(val, max_val, limit_yellow, limit_red){

  var gauge_Temp = new LinearGauge({
    renderTo: document.getElementById('myCanvas'),
    width: 150,
    height: 370,
    borderRadius: 20,
    borders: 0,
    barStrokeWidth: 20,
    minorTicks: 10,
    majorTicks: [0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100],
    highlights: [
        {
          "from": limit_yellow,
            "to": limit_red,
            "color": "rgba(255, 255, 0, .75)"
        },
        {
            "from": limit_red,
            "to": 100,
            "color": "rgba(200, 50, 50, .75)"
        }
    ],

    units: "°C",
    colorValueBoxShadow: false
  }).draw();

  gauge_Temp.update({ animation:false,value: val  });
  document.getElementById("crit_Temp").textContent =max_val+"°C";
}
```

Sorry for the german... "nutzwerte" is just the name for the data I use.

Comment: 224MB is a lot! Can you give some more info about the canvas (width + height) and why it becomes so large?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. The sensor provides me every 500ms new values not only temperature and rpm. I only use every 5th value. The usage of my smartphone ressources are insane after 20min.
        width: 150,
        height: 370,
Why is the width and height of the gauge resposible for the memory use?
Its realy interesting, never thozght about that.

Comment: Could you share a minimal code example which triggers this bug? As far as I know there is no way to increase memory limit for Canvas elements.

Comment: Hi @HelderSepulveda I allready did =)
https://github.com/Mikhus/canvas-gauges/issues/177

Comment: Why is this supposed to be bug? Maybe I just adjusted it not right. Maybe s.o knows how to fix. I googled for hours. Why not asking here?

Comment: Even if you adjusted something incorrectly in he canvas gauges, it should not leak memory to the point of hitting the max limit, But now that I think about it twice maybe someone can give you a workaround here...

Comment: @HelderSepulveda thank you for editing my post. Its my first one and I didn't manage the formatting right...

Comment: The only thing I could think of is try to reproduce the error on a web browser, that would help identify if it is only on the IPhone or the issue is present everywhere...

Comment: I see you also reported this a while back: https://github.com/Mikhus/canvas-gauges/issues/171 and no reply from the owner... try reaching out directly, he has an email on his profile: https://github.com/Mikhus

Comment: I will write him direktly.
I tryed this on an Android phone and with the google chrome console but it didn't monitor me the error... the gauges just vanished and the app crashed after ~20min. I can only test things on real devices (iPhone and Andorid) because the data is provided by bluetooth low energy. I also tested the app on an Android phone of my colleague -same result: the gauges vanishing and the app stops working. Only on iOS the safari concole returns me this error

Comment: Mock the data, create a function that outputs random stuff with the schema you need, a webApp is a lot easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: I mocked the data with random values in an interval of 1 secound. After ~4h and 15.000 values the simulation stoped without any error... The owner still has not answerd me via mail nor github...